# How can i watch df.pivot_table output in debug mode in pycharm?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been handed over a project, which i am debugging right now to understand the process but i am not able to move ahead as df.pivot_table returns error

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

and i am not able to move ahead.

Comment: Add a breakpoint and examine your program: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/examining-suspended-program.html

Comment: the problem i am raising is of this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70865175/pandas-pivot-table-nonetype-object-is-not-callable

Comment: I really need to find an alternative of pd.pivot_table or someway to see if i can see the result in debug mode .. only then i can step over in debug, else it throws error of NoneType, and working absolutely well if i just run the program.